# Connect linux mint to university proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, cntlm

I am trying to connect my linux to my university's proxy. In other places I have always used cntlm, but this time I can't get it to work.

My configuration changes:

```
Username    myuser
#Domain     ######### I put the domain blank because I'm not sure what it is
Password    4h/89159

Proxy       proxy.example.org:3128
Listen      3131
```

CNTLM logs:

```
Proxy returning invalid challenge!
```

sudo cntlm -I -M http://www.google.com

```
Password: 
Config profile  1/4... Proxy doesn't offer NTLM or BASIC

Wrong credentials, invalid URL or proxy doesn't support NTLM nor BASIC.
```

Putting the proxy directly in the terminal and try with wget:

```
export https_proxy=https://username:password@proxy.example.org:3128/
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.example.org:3128/

wget --spider google.com                                       
Resolving proxy.example.org (proxy.example.org)... 10.12.1.172, 10.12.1.171
Connecting to proxy.example.org (proxy.example.org)|10.12.1.172|:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Remote file does not exist -- broken link!!!
```

However, using the browser proxy, it directly asks me for my username and password and I connect to the internet without problems.

Any idea how to fix this.